# Fitting the label text of tab widet Qt

Tags: qt

I have a tab widget with two tabs in it in my Qt application. When I set the label text for a tab to a long word like 'Difference', some of the text goes out of the boundary of the tab and is not shown. How do I fix this so that the entire label text fits exactly in the tab?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt receives that style from OS. By default on Windows text isn't truncated. You can set it manually using

```
QTabWidget::setElideMode( Qt::ElideNone );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`elideMode`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtabwidget.html#elideMode-prop) would be helpful for you.

Try setting the value to `Qt::ElideNone` which will not show the ellipsis in the text, so I am guessing it might show the entire text.